# Deploying DeployStudio

Tags: mac-osx, deployment, xserve, netboot, deploystudio

*Also see question [How do you disable or uninstall NetRestore from a NetBoot server?](https://serverfault.com/questions/7870).*

*Edited to add this link to [a great document](http://web.me.com/driley/iWeb/Dual-boot_Lab_files/DeployStudio_Guide.pdf) that I should have been using all along but didn't find until it was too late.*

I've successfully removed NetRestore from my NetBoot server and am trying to install DeployStudio.  It's my understanding that the bootable NBI should be automatically generated by running the DeployStudio Assistant, but the documentation isn't very clear on this.

Do I need to run the separate "Create a DeployStudio NetBoot Set" function in the Assistant? The Assistant dialogs are confusing here because they specify that you must create the NBI on "the latest Mac OS X system you have."  Do I create the NBI on a Mac client and then move it to the Xserve, or create it on the Xserve even though it's not the newest OS X device we own?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created the NBI on the server and it is booting my clients successfully so far.

Also, the issue I reported in the previous question, where the NetBoot service appears to be crashing, does not seem to be affecting the performance of the service.  The bug looks like it's only affecting the Server Admin GUI.

Answer (score 1):

your NBI files should be created on a client computer not your server. the client host machine should be the latest and best you can get hold of as an NBI created on this will boot everything else you have including laptops. it's then copied back to your server running DeployStudio and selected as the boot image file in the NetBoot service.